# String.Format - Problem with Argument list

Tags: c#, string

```
string nr = "42245555" //just an example number
string expression = "{5}{6}/{7}{8}";

string res = String.Format(expression, new string[] {
nr[0].ToString(),nr[1].ToString(),
nr[2].ToString(), nr[3].ToString(), 
nr[4].ToString(), nr[5].ToString(), 
nr[6].ToString(), nr[7].ToString() 
});
```

Why is this not working and how can I solve it?
I want expression to be either `"{5}{6}/{7}{8}" or "{0}{3}/{7}{1}"` or whatever the user wants.

Comment: What is not working, what error messages do you see? What behaviour do you expect?

Comment: "this [is] not working" is a horribly bad error report from a programmer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameters in expression must start from `"{0}"` and the `array` must contain the same number of parameters as the expression and it must be an array of objects : `new object[]{...`

Comment: Being an array of strings seems to be fine too.

Answer (score 8):

You must supply at least the same number of parameters (or an array with at least the same number of elements) as the highest placeholder value plus one (placeholder values are zero indexed)

Max placeholder value {3}, you must supply at least four additional parameters.

Try this:

```
string res = String.Format(expression,
  nr[0], nr[1],
  nr[2], nr[3], 
  nr[4], nr[5], 
  nr[6], nr[7]);
```

Note that I took out new string[] { ... } I also took out all the `ToString()` because they are not required.

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'char' to 'string'

Comment: Additionally, the expression refers to argument {8}, i.e. the 9th argument, but there are only 8 given.

Comment: No it isn't. String.Format can accept chars as parameters (which is what is being passed) - It can accept any object and string.Format will call ToString() itself if it doesn't get a string. So, it is not required unless you are doing something else that I'm not seeing. Why exactly do you think ToString() is required?

Comment: Are you also removing the new string[] { ... } as I have shown in my code? I'm guessing you are not, hence the "Cannot implicity conver type 'char' to 'string'

Comment: `string.Format("{0} {1}",new string[]{"A","B"})` prints `A B`. So it looks like this answer("You have passed a single additional argument into the string.Format so as far as string.Format is concerned the only valid placeholder is {0}") is wrong.

Comment: The code snippet in and of itself does work assuming that expression uses placeholder {0} to {7}. I didn't initially notice {8} which is where it falls down, however, that is still explained in the answer.

Comment: The part were you state that only a single parameter is valid is simply wrong. The parameters 0 to 7 are valid, because the array contains 8 elements.

Comment: Ah... Okay. When the single additional argument is an array it still works. However, under normal circumstances it would not. I'll correct that part of the answer.

Comment: It only works with an array with reference type members. Because array covariance only works for reference types.

Answer (score 7):

The relevant overload of `Format` is:

```
public static string Format(string format,  params Object[] args)
```

This means you can either call it like this:

```
Format("...",new object[]{...})//Each array element is used
```

Or with the objects directly as parameters:

```
Format("...",object1, object2,...)//the objects are used
```

Unlike what I originally thought, a `string[]` does indeed go into the first variant of this code. This is due to [array covariance in C#/.net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664572(v=vs.71).aspx) which allows a `string[]` to be implicitly converted to a `object[]`.

```
string.Format("{0} {1}",new string[]{"A","B"})
```

prints `A B`.

On the other hand if you try similar code with a `int[]` it won't work:

```
string.Format("{0} {1}",new int[]{1,2})
```

Will throw an exception because it goes into the second variation, and thus only a single parameter of type `int[]` is seen by `string.Format`. This difference is because array covariance only works on arrays with members that are a *reference* type like `string` and not a *value* type like `int`. This means `int[]` is not implicitly convertible to `object[]`.

So the problem with your original code is probably just that you used the index `{8}` which is out of range.

Answer (score 2):

- Your parameters are numbered 0..7, easy to read back. Yet you use `{8}` : Index out of Range
- You don't need the `new string[] {  }` around the parameters. It is allowed though.
- without the `new string[] {  }` you don't need the `.ToString()` calls either.

Answer (score 0):

IF ur user wants {5}{6}/{7}{8} , then ur code will be:

```
String.Format("{0}{1}/{2}{3}",nr[4],nr[5],nr[6],nr[7]);
```

ur indexes in the expression must always start with 0..In my example if u want to display this for strings.. u start by 0,1,2,3.. 0 for nr[4], 1 for nr[5], 2 for nr[6], 3 for nr[7], etc..

Answer (score -1):

You have to use:

```
nr.Substring(...)
```

in String.Format([expression], [values]) expression is a string represent a string with placeholders while values are inserted in those placeholders.

**updated**

```
string nr = "42245555" //just an example number   


string res = String.Format("{0}{1}/{2}{3}", new string[] {
nr[5].ToString(),nr[6].ToString(),
nr[7].ToString(), nr[8].ToString()
});
```

or

```
string res = String.Format("{0}{1}/{2}{3}", new string[] {
nr[0].ToString(),nr[3].ToString(),
nr[7].ToString(), nr[1].ToString()
});
```

Comment: You dont need new string[] ant ToStrings because Format accepts [params](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) objects.